# Laravel View [auth.login] not found after downloaded form bitbucket

Tags: error-handling, laravel-5.1

My laravel project still online without any error, but when i downloaded my project form bitbucket to want to change something. it give me two error
[image: View [auth.login] not found.]

and an another error bellow the first error
[image: failed to open stream: No such file or directory]

i tried everything what i have on internet
i tried `composer-install` `composer clear-cache` `php artian clear-compiled` but noting works for me.

Comment: try this command and check `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: not working, still same error

Comment: check that, your these directories is present in project or not ?
`storage->framework->sessions` check these 3 directories, if not exists, then create it

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder

bootstrap/cache
Rename config.php to config.php_

Hope this helps...

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does renaming some file solve such an error? What is the difference to `composer clear-cache` which the OP already used?